# Download a file from a Server with double ssh

Tags: linux, unix, ssh, download

I connect to a Server with ssh

Step 1:

```
$ ssh userid@something.com
```

and then it asks for password and everything is ok

Then I connect to a DB
Step2:

```
$ssh user1@smthing_else
```

and then it asks for password and everything is ok

Now when I type ls I can see the file that I want to download...

How can I download this file on my Desktop..??

Comment: use `tftp` to download and make sure `tftp server` is running on server.

Comment: you can download file using sftp to download file,or you can user gui tools like filezilla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to scp the file twice in order to bring it to local m/c if you don't have direct access. First ssh to the server 1 and run the command to download it. Then run this command again from your local m/c.

```
scp -r -i path-to-secret-key ubuntu@ec2-address:/home/ubuntu/app-folder-location /home/user/local-mc-location
```

As you don't have the key, use the below command

```
scp -r ubuntu@ec2-address:/home/ubuntu/app-folder-location /home/user/local-mc-location
```

**Update:**
path-to-secret-key is the private key address which is used in ec2 instances to ssh. They are used for authentication and are present in home/.ssh/private-key. They have a permission of 400 and are either .pem extension for unix m/c's or ppk extension for windows m/c's

Comment: can you explain path-to-secret-key? btw, the more common way to write this is path/to/secret/key, also would be easier to read if you wrote path/to/local and path/to/remote instead of /home/ubuntu, etc..

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can't directly reach the "inner" host from the outside? In that case you have to ssh into the outer host, then you can use `scp` to copy the file from the inner host to the outer one. Accordingly, you can then copy the file to your local pc from the outer host with scp (or whatever you can use in that case).

scp works like this (to copy a local file to a remote host):

```
scp myfile.txt user@somehost.com:/home/user/whatever
```

resp. like this (remote to local):

```
scp user@somehost.com:/home/user/whatever/myfile.txt .
```

Comment: 1) -r is useful to recurse over files/directories 2) explain where the file is saved in the second part?